# PC connected to two networks but no Internet access

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm trying to set up two networks on my PC but am encountering an issue when connected to both.

The PC connects to one network via Ethernet. This network has no Internet but is essential to operating software on the PC. The PC is manually configured to have an IP address 172.19.10.81, a 255.255.192.0 subnet mask, and a default gateway of 172.**19**.1.1. The default gateway is very important and must be entered.

The second network interface is a USB WiFi stick and gets its IP address via DHCP. It receives an IP address in the 172.**20**.X.X range, with a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask. Of course, DHCP assigns a default gateway to the wireless router.

Although these are two different networks, they do not play well with each other. Whenever the Ethernet cable is plugged in, the wireless network does not work (no Internet access). Unplugging the Ethernet cable allows the PC access to the Internet. It seems as though Windows is trying to route Internet traffic through the 172.19 network, instead of the 172.20 one. This is an issue for me because I cannot remote into the machine through the wireless network *and* monitor the software's activity at the same time.

I have looked at some answers and have added a metric to the networks (1 for the wireless, and 2 for the Ethernet) but it had no effect. Also, some answers suggest removing the default gateway from the connection that has no Internet but I am not able to do this.

I am looking for a solution to this problem, or a suggestion for another method of getting both networks to work simultaneously.

Comment: Open a command prompt and check out what `route /?` displays.

Comment: I've seen onboard chips automatically disable wifi when a lan conncetion is available. Can you see if you can ping the wifi router 172.20.x.x when both are available? Do note that you will have to change the LAN subnet to 255.255.255.0 to properly test this. In fact, this may very well be your issue.

Comment: Don't use a default gateway on an interface without access to the internet. Use specific routes out that interface and a default route out towards the gateway of the other interface that can actually connect to the internet.